# any facebook api can get change of facebook relationship?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

how to get `change of relationship`?

of course , we can get current relationship status, (graph api , "me" )

but how to get history? for example, maybe  1/1/2000 change married status from single to married. i want to get this change.....

i also try to use "me/feed" , still can not get `change of relationship`.....

if facebook API doesn't support this feature, can i get information via grab facebook page/html ?

development platform : c# / asp.net

Answer (score 1):

History data like this isn't available from Facebook.  What your app could do is use the [real-time updates api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) to subscribe to profile changes and build up that history of the user on your own server.

Comment: thank you for your answer, can i get history data from homepage ? ie: access index.html  try to download and analyze html?